# Python identify if variable is NoneType

Tags: python, nonetype

In the below loop, initially `lines_hp[0]` is not a `NoneType`. But after some operations, it will become `NoneType` and I want to break the loop when that happens. After some iterations of the loop, `lines_hp[0]` changes to `NoneType` but when I want to identify it using `lines_hp[0] is not None`, I get the error: `'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`. How can I fix this?

```
while lines_hp[0] is not None:
    print lines_hp[0] is not None
    #some operation to change lines_hp[0]
```

I have gone through numerous SO questions and answers on how to detect the NoneType item but I am still getting the above error.

Comment: Are you sure `lines_hp[0]` becomes none or does `lines_hp` become none?

Comment: looks like `lines_hp` becomes None instead of `lines_hp[0]`

Comment: You are confusing the list with the first element of the list. That is, do you have a line like `lines_hp = None` or `lines_hp[0] = None` in the body of the loop?

Comment: From the error message, it looks like the whole array/list/whatever that is (or rather was) is of type NoneType. Try removing the `[0]` in the check

Comment: Holy smokes good work comment team

Comment: Well, guess that was easy. What a silly mistake on my part. Fastest response to any question I've posted by far. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is **not `lines_hp[0]` that became `None`**, but **`lines_hp` itself is now `None`**. Python is complaining that you want to obtain an index from a `None` object (like `None[0]`) and this fails.

You should check that first:

```
while lines_hp is not None and lines_hp[0] is not None:
    print lines_hp[0] is not None
    #some operation to change lines_hp[0]
```